# How to write to a cloud storage bucket with a firebase cloud function triggered from firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

To make sure this is as clean and isolated as possible, I created a new test project with nothing in it other than these steps.

I then enabled cloud firestore in the console. I created a new collection called "blarg" (great name, eh!). I added a document to it, and used the auto-id, then added a field named "humpty" with the string dumpty. It looks like this in the console:

[image]

I created a directory called `signatures` in the storage section of the firebase console. I want to write a file into this directory when my function (below) triggers.

I then added a cloud function with the following code. It shows up (I assume) correctly in the functions section, with the name `testItOut` and triggering on the event `document.update` for `/blarg/{eventId}`.:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
require('firebase-admin').initializeApp();

exports.testItOut = functions.firestore
    .document('blarg/{docId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    console.log( "Inside #testItOut" );
    const projectId = 'testing-60477';
    const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const storage = new Storage({
        projectId,
    });
    let bucketName = 'signatures'; 
    let fileName = 'temp.txt';
    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
    console.log( `Writing out to ${tempFilePath}` );
    fs.writeFileSync(tempFilePath, "something!" );

    return storage
        .bucket( bucketName )
        .upload( tempFilePath )
        .then( () => fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath) )
        .catch(err => console.error('ERROR inside upload: ', err) );
    });
```

The package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.7.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

If I change the value of the key "humpty" I see the function invocation. But, I get the error inside the logs.

```
ERROR inside upload:  { ApiError: testing-60477@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to signatures/temp.txt.
    at Object.parseHttpRespBody (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:193:30)
    at Object.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:131:18)
...
```

[image]

This is as simple as it can get, I'd assume. What am I doing wrong? I thought calling `initializeApp()` gave my function rights to write to the storage bucket for the account automatically?

The only strange error I see is that billing is not setup. I thought this was necessary only if you use external APIs. Is Google Storage an "external API?" The log message does not indicate that's the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was that I mistakenly thought the call to `bucket` was to set the **subdirectory** inside the bucket. Instead of `bucket('signatures')` I should have made it an empty call like `bucket()` and then provided an options parameter (like `{ destination: '/signatures/temp.txt' }`) for the `upload` call:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.testItOut = functions.firestore
    .document('blarg/{docId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    console.log( "Inside #testItOut" );
    const storage = admin.storage()
    let fileName = 'temp.txt';
    let destination = '/signatures/temp.txt';
    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
    console.log( `Writing out to ${tempFilePath}` );
    fs.writeFileSync(tempFilePath, "something!" );

    return storage
        .bucket()
        .upload( tempFilePath, { destination } )
        .then( () => fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath) )
        .catch(err => console.error('ERROR inside upload: ', err) );
    });
```

I got confused because I saw lots of examples in firebase docs where there are calls to `bucket("albums")` (like this: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.6.x/Bucket#getFiles) and assumed this meant the bucket can be used to set a **subdirectory** for uploads. It's obvious to me now the difference, but I was thrown off because the calls to bucket did not look like `bucketname-12345.appspot.com` as I see in the firebase storage console.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother trying to use the Google Cloud Storage SDK like this:

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const storage = new Storage({
        projectId,
    });
```

Instead, just use the Admin SDK after you initialize it.  The Admin SDK wraps the Google Cloud Storage SDK.  When you initialize admin, you are also implicitly initializing all of the components it wraps.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()
const storage = admin.storage()
// Now use storage just like you would use @google-cloud/storage
```

The default service account that's used when you init admin with no args like this should have write access to your project's default storage bucket.

Comment: I wish it were so, but I still get the same error even after using the code you provided. I also tried upgrading my account to remove the billing account error message, but this (as expected) does not fix things. I believe the code is exactly as you specified (as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/xrd/2d24016d16a7e12d7b280c56541af2d5#file-index-js-L10).

Comment: Something may be misconfigured in your project. I do this all the time.  Is this a brand new project?

Comment: BTW you should not init the admin SDK every time the function is run.  Just do it once.

Comment: OK, but isn't your code above implying that? You are creating the storage object outside of the function?

Comment: I moved the require statement and `initializeApp()` outside of the triggering function (https://gist.github.com/xrd/0bca1c8cbd17be97c7ebd796dc6e0892#file-index-js-L5). But, still same error.

Comment: This is a brand new project. I have nothing else inside it and created it from scratch to isolate my problem.

Comment: The code I showed is just to illustrate the sequence to get a working storage object.  But I'm stumped why you would get that error.

Comment: Is there a way to query the permissions of a service account? I did not do anything to modify it, but perhaps there is something in a parent permission that I unknowingly changed months ago and is inherited? I'm stumped as well. Thanks for your review at least.

Comment: If you can list out the very exact steps you took to reproduce this, from the moment of Firebase project creation, and you're certain you're not doing anything wrong, that could become a bug report.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I'll do that. Maybe I can create/setup all from command line and see if there is a difference. I did all this from the web console.

Comment: Command line setup did not work (and some steps need to be completed inside the web ui anyway). I'll see if I can get more information and file a bug.